# page number latex

Tags: page, number

Sorry for the message in french, I'm starting again my question.
I have a problem with page number. Even if I use the command :  \pagestyle{empty}
my first page keep a number but not the others. I don't understand where is my error.
Thanks for help

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\title{Title}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
%\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[scale=.15]{miashs}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
        frame code={}
        center title,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=PowderBlue!50,
        colframe=white,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0cm,12cm)
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Blablabla
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{textblock*}

\newpage
blablabla


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you feel more comfortable asking in French I suggest you have a look at https://texnique.fr/osqa/. The site has the same general system as TeX.SX, but it is in French. Here the *lingua franca* is English and questions should be asked (and will be answered) in English.

Comment: sorry i started again and thanks for the informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\maketitle`, and `pagestyle{plain}` after `\newpage` works.

*Edit*: as @Mico pointed in a comment, removing `\pagestyle{empty}` from the preamble makes adding `\pagestyle{...}` after `\newpage` unneeded.

Unrelated: the `hyperref` package should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (mainly `cleveref`). Also, the language options of `babel` should be loaded as `\documentclass` options, so that all packages which are language-aware be informed.

So the code should now be this:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\title{Title}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
%\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[scale=.15]{miashs}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    frame code={}
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=PowderBlue!50,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    }
    } 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0cm,12cm)
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Blablabla
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{textblock*}

\newpage
 blablabla

\end{document}
```

If you want  page numbering to start at the first numbered page, add `\pagenumbering{arabic}` (or whatever style you want) jus after `\newpage` to reset the page counter.

Comment: It's right i can keep all my commands with this solution . thanks for help

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you take a look at the possibilities of the `titling` package, which greatly helps customising titkle pages.

Comment: Great, I will explore it, thanks again !

Comment: @Mico: I didn't notice it,  in the  O.P.'s code. I wondered why `\thispagestyle{empty}` seemed to act like `\pagestyle{empty}`. I'll edit my answer (with credits, of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `\documentclass[svgnames,titlepage]{article}` you get the titlepage witout a number.
Then you can choose your pagestyle with something like.

```
…
\maketitle
\pagestyle{plain}
…
```

Comment: I've learnt something! I had completely forgotten this option.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution but in my report i have lot of commands to customize my first page and with this command i cannot do this. Thanks for help